# Test if a collection is loaded in Spring DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having troubles testing whether a collection is loaded in Spring DataJpaTest.

For that I have created an entity that has id and list of items as seen below. The list should be lazy-loaded (so I am assuming it should not be loaded in the test).

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "examples")
public class Example {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "example", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<ExampleElement> collection;

}
```

Repository code looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Example, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT e FROM Example e")
  List<Example> findAllActive();

}
```

In the test I am creating a new Example entity, generating the collection, saving the entity to database and after that getting entities from database and checking whether the collections are initialized.
Test code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class ExampleRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private ExampleRepository repository;

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    Example example = new Example();
    example.setCollection(Utils.generateCollection()))
    repository.save(example);

    List<Example> actives = repository.findAllActive();

    // tests in a loop whether the collection is initialized which should return false
  }
```

I have tried the following:

- Injecting TestEntityManager and getting the PersistenceUnitUtil from there using  `em.getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil()` and calling the `isLoaded(actives.get(0).getCollection())` and `isLoaded(actives.get(0), "collection")` methods - both return true
- Calling `Hibernate.isInitialized(actives.get(0).getCollection())` and `Hibernate.isPropertyInitialized(actives.get(0), "collection")` methods, which both return true as well.
- Checking what the collection contains - it is a PersistentBag containing the elements. I expect it to be null instead.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having similar issues, where I cannot replicate spring JPA behaviour w.r.t. lazy-loaded collections because in my tests, all my entity objects are eagerly loaded. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @MichielHaisma sadly no